# How to call a constructor from a mixedin mixin template

Tags: templates, constructor, metaprogramming, d

If I do something like

```
mixin template T() {
  float y;
  this(float y_){
    y = y_;
  }
}
class C {
  mixin T!() t;
  int x;
  this(int x_, float y_){
    x = x_;
    this(y_);
  }
}
//
C c = new C(5, 7.0f);
```

This gives the error
`constructor C.this (int x_, float y_) is not callable using argument types (float)`. On the line that contains `this(y_);` in C's constructor, which seems to imply that C can't see the constructor imported from T. Though, it should.

Obviously `t.this(...)` and `T!().this(...)` don't work.

The most obvious workaround I can think of is like (a proxy):

```
template T(...) {
  void constructor(...){...}
  this(Args...)(Args args){ constructor(args); }
}
...
class C {
   mixin T!() t;
   this(...){
     t.constructor(...);
   }
}
```

But that sucks because it puts more knowledge overhead on T (using the constructor requires doing something special)

Is there any way to call t's constructor in a non-weird (and non-special-case) way? Also, is this a bug? If not, why does it work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that things mixed into an aggregate via mixin templates [are not inserted into the aggregate's overload set](https://dlang.org/spec/template-mixin.html#mixin_scope).

For normal methods the way to get around that is to use an alias into the scope introduced by the template mixin like so:

```
mixin template T()
{
    void foo()
    {
    }
}

class C
{
    mixin T!() t;
    alias foo = t.foo;

    void foo(int _)
    {
        foo();
    }
}
```

However, for constructors, the analogue doesn't work and [it's a reported bug](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11500):

```
    alias this = t.this;    // Won't compile
    alias __ctor = t.__ctor // Using the hidden __ctor name won't compile, either
```

If you don't need to call the mixed in constructor from outside, you can call it via the builtin name:

```
mixin template T()
{
    float y;
    this(float y_)
    {
        y = y_;
    }
}
class C
{
    mixin T!() t;
    int x;
    this(int x_, float y_)
    {
        x = x_;
        t.__ctor(y_); // This
    }
}
```